# Centering text within div containing sibling image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to vertically and horizontally center some text inside a div.  The div contains a sibling image also.

```css
.div-table {
  display: table;
  vertical-align: middle;
  z-index: 2
}
.div-table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg" height="250" width="250" />
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='div-table'>
      <div class='div-table-cell'>
        <p>my text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have prepared a jsfiddle with where I am at: https://jsfiddle.net/p3wur6qj/1/

I thought having:

```
display: table-cell;
```

and

```
display: table;
```

around the containing divs would achieve this but it hasn't.

Comment: Is [this](https://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements/) what you're tring to do? The `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` "magic"?

Comment: Please check if this works for you: https://jsfiddle.net/wy0qonb9/

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use flexbox for centering the text both horizontally and vertically.

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block; /*same size as the image*/
  position: relative;
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /*center horizontally*/
  align-items: center; /*center vertically*/
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg" height="200" width="200" />
  <div class='content'>
    <p>my text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or, using the `position` + `transform` tricks.

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /*position -50% of the element size*/
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg" height="200" width="200" />
  <div class='content'>
    <p>my text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```